# Where it says longsword +3 and short sword +2, what does the +3 and +2 mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, new-players

In the following example character, in this case Valeros:

http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/npcCodex/iconic/valeros.html

What does the +3 and +2 mean in relation to his weapons?
Are these magical/enhanced weapons?

Also, how do you calculate the damage from these weapons?

Comment: The other answer covers the mechanics so I thought I'd offer an old, more lore'ey explaination that I remember reading in Dragon magazine. The +1, +2 etc indicated that the weapon exists in additional, higher dimensions, thus causing additional damage. This also explains why some creatures were immune to 'normal' damage but not the +1/+2's, because they exist in these dimensions only. (I'll see if I can find the exact issue/page and update if I can)

Answer (score 28):

**That's his attack bonuses**

The entry you're seeing is a stat block for the character. The headings there under his attacks indicate his various attack options, their accuracy (that's the +2/+3) and their damage. So, in this case, we have:

> Melee longsword +3 (1d8+3/19–20), short sword +2 (1d6+1/19–20) or longsword +5 (1d8+3/19–20)

This means that his first option is a full attack with both weapons; he attacks with the longsword at a +3 bonus to his D20 roll and deals 1d8+3 if it hits, critting for double damage on a natural roll of 19-20. He then attacks with his short sword at +2, dealing 1d6+1 damage and again critting for double on a 19-20. *Alternately*, he can attack with just the longsword at +5, dealing 1d8+3 and critting for double damage on a natural roll of a 19-20.

Monster entries work similarly.

**Calculating Attack Bonuses**

Attack bonuses are calculated, generally speaking, as follows:

Base Attack Bonus (BAB) + Strength Modifier (melee attacks) or Dexterity Modifier (ranged attacks or melee attacks made with the Weapon Finesse feat) + the weapon's bonuses (such as bonuses for being masterwork or magical) + magical bonuses (such as the *true strike* spell) + any circumstance bonuses (such as flanking) - penalties (such as from Two-Weapon Fighting or spells).

In some cases a character may have additional attacks from a high Base Attack Bonus. In this case, the additional attacks are called 'iteratives', and are made at a lower attack bonus - for example, a sixth level fighter with a +1 longsword and an 18 strength would swing at +11 for his first attack roll, and +6 for his second. Making more than one attack in this fashion is a Full Attack, a full-round action that eats up your resources for the turn except for your 1 swift action and your five-foot step.

You can discover more information about specific bonuses and penalties (such as from two-weapon fighting) through the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/).

**Calculating Damage**

Damage dealt by weapon attacks is calculated as follows:

XdX (the weapon's base damage, such as 1d8 for a longsword) + strength modifier (for one-handed melee weapons or thrown weapons; two-handed melee weapons deal 1.5 x strength modifier) + the weapon's enhancement bonus (if any) + any feat bonuses (such as from Weapon Specialization) + any circumstance bonuses (such as from making a Charge) + the weapon's properties (such as *flaming*) + any magical bonuses (such as from spells) - penalties.

Unlike with attack rolls, damage rolls are taken in their totality and then *compared* against the victim for any mitigating effects; that is, your total damage rolled does not change when confronted with damage reduction or damage vulnerability, but the damage the enemy *takes* will. Your DM may ask you to calculate this yourself, or s/he may choose to do so.

Comment: That clears things up a little bit. How are the bonuses calculated?

Comment: Great answer. For completeness reasons, could you add a paragraph about damage calculation? It's in the question, so I guess it should be answered as well.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular example of a lvl 1 fighter there's no magic weapons. It's his AB (Attack Bonus (final/adjusted/what you add to the roll))

"Melee longsword +3 (1d8+3/19–20), short sword +2 (1d6+1/19–20) OR longsword +5 (1d8+3/19–20)"

The "OR" separates the two attack modes, full attack and single attack.
For to-hit rolls, he gets BAB +1 (from fighter lvl) and also +3 from Strength (16). He also gets +1 with Longsword from Weapon Focus Feat. That makes the Longsword +5 block. When two weapon fighting he gets 2 attacks in a round but at -2 penalty (he would have had bigger penalties if he had a bigger offhand weapon or no two weapon fighting feat) so he gets +3 with Longsword and only +2 with Short Sword (cause he has no weapon focus feat with that weapon).
Also note that his Strength adds +3 to damage, but only +1 for the offhand (Short Sword) rounded down.